# How to change the SelectedValue of a DropDownList before Bind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-2.0, formview

Basically I have a `Customers` table with one of the fields being `Gender`, and I'm making a form that allows the user to update the customer information, in this case the gender. The default SelectedValue for Gender is either "Male" or "Female" and I want to change "Male" to 0 and "Female" to 1 before actually binding it to the database. I got as far as having this as my code behind:

```
protected void fmvCustomerDetails_ItemUpdating(object sender, FormViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    if (fmvCustomerDetails.editGender.val.Equals("Male"))
        fmvCustomerDetails.editGender.val = 0;
}
```

fmvCustomerDetails is the ID of my FormView object and editGender is the ID of the DropDownList. For reasons that is too troublesome to explain, I can't just change the database to accept "Male" or "Female" as the input.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a combobox (DropDownList is only the DropDownStyle of the ComboBox class), you should use the DisplayMember to be the gender (male, female) and ValueMember to be the 0 and 1.
This way, you won't have to do any trick changing values before pushing to your database. You can just bind your field.
You could create an ArrayList that contains both the value wanted and the string you want to display. Then bind the value to the ValueMember and the string to the DisplayMember.

```
    ArrayList arrGender = new ArrayList();
    arrGender.Add(new { id = 0, sex = "Male" });
    arrGender.Add(new { id = 1, sex = "Female" });

    cbGender.DataSource = arrGender;
    cbGender.DisplayMember = "sex";
    cbGender.ValueMember = "id";
```

If you want to get the number associated with your DropDownList you can get it through SelectedValue.

```
    cbGender.SelectedValue             //Returns the 0 or the 1
```

Comment: I'm not using a ComboBox as it allows the user to input something else other than "Male" or "Female"

Comment: If the user can input something else, what value are you gonna give it? If you don't know, there is gonna be a problem pushing it's value. If you know, why not add it directly into your list?

Comment: Not too sure whether I get you. The user will only have 2 options to choose for the Gender field, Male or Female, which is in my DropDownList. The reason I choose to use DropDownList over a ComboBox is so that I know that the user can only give me two kinds of values, saving me from writing a whole bunch of unnecessary validations.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the items in your DropDownList so that the text is "Male" and the value is "0"?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround that circumvents this problem, therefore I'll be deleting this question.

I'm marking this as the answer as apparently I need to have an accepted answer before I can delete my question. (weird)

Comment: if you want the answer to you question, I edited my previous post